# Android, toolbar + item + spiner + fragment

Tags: android, toolbar

Друзья у меня есть 2 fragment-(a) на которых есть spinner и есть toolbar на котором есть item(иконка представлена в виде png). Мне нужно чтоб когда выбираешь одно из полей spiner-(a) у меня менялась item(иконка) в toolbar. Не могу понять где вообще нужно делать реализацию, плиз подскажите!

Comment: Покажите код тулбара и метод, который срабатывает при выборе итема.

Comment: изменение айтемов `Toolbar`, если он назначен как `ActionBar` делается в `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`

Answer (score 2):

Может помочь следующий урок: [StartAndroid. Урок 56. Spinner – выпадающий список](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/115-urok-56-spinner-vypadajuschij-spisok.html)

```
// устанавливаем обработчик нажатия
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
    // показываем позицию нажатого элемента
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  }
});
```

Только вместо Toast.makeText вызовите изменение иконки